# Faster way of removing items from list

Tags: python, list, memory, time, big-o

I have a list that is around 10M in length. Each index contains a dictionary

so for instance...

```
l = [{'id': 'y'}, {'id', 'x'}, {'id', 'z'} ... ]
```

I have another list with items that I want to remove

```
m = ['y', 'z']
```

I tried

```
l = [i for i in l if i['id'] not in m]
```

But as expected a run time of `O(n^3)` is not amazing.
My second approach is to create a new dictionary to store the index of the items I wish to remove:

```
temp = {'y': 0, 'z': 2, ... }

for i in range(0, len(temp)):
    del l[temp[m[-1]]]
    del m[-1]
```

This did improve the execution time by A LOT (from somewhere around an hour to a few seconds or minutes for datasets of 1M). But since I'm storing the indexes somewhere, the memory used is rather high

My question is: is there a more efficient way of removing items from a large list in `O(n)` time and yet not use so much memory?

Comment: is your list sorted? like in your example? if so you can use binary search ... and that should provide significant improvements

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yup. The list is sorted based on a `time` key in the dictionaries

Comment: Did this line really work? `l = [i for i in l if i not in m]`. `i` is a dictionary and `m` is a list of keys. Assuming the dictionary will always have one entry, do you not want to do `l = [i for i in l if i.keys()[0] not in m]`. Second, why is this O(n^3)? You just loop through the list once. If the element is not in `m` keep it, else skip it.

Comment: @pushkin Ah my bad the actual code is correct. I'll edit the question

Comment: is each element really just `{"id":"N"}`?

Comment: @JoranBeasley nope. I consists of other key value pairs. It's actually dictionaries of comment from the [reddit corpus](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/3bxlg7/i_have_every_publicly_available_reddit_comment/)

Comment: i think your question should be is there any data structure that allows bulk removal efficiently? given a list as data structure, there really isn't many creative things to do.

Comment: Make `m` into a set, not a list. Sets are based on dictionaries which gives them a much faster lookup for the `i['id'] not in m` test instead of checking membership in a list. When you did the second approach, how did you get the index of items to remove, and didn't that take ages? Roughly how many items are there to be removed compared to the 10M list size? - 1K? 1M? 9.9M?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I looped the list once to get the indexes. I figured that it'll still be faster than creating nested loops

Comment: @MonoShiro ... and to the other questions?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Sorry for the late reply. It depends on the datasets (I'm splitting 53M into 10M chunks). Some removes 4M+ while other removes a few hundrend K. I've tried using set (see below)

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you'll get much better than:

```
s = set(m)
l = [i for i in l if i['id'] not in s]
```

This would likely be much quicker then creating a loop and deleting items one at a time.  There is usually a tradeoff though between memory and speed - this should be reasonably fast, but will use up to twice the memory of your list as it creates a new one.

**Caveat**:  When I say "I doubt you'll get much better than..." I'm talking about standard Python.  A numerical library like Pandas or Numpy could likely do much better in terms of both memory and time.

Comment: I've just tried that on a list of 3127 dictionaries (took 0.2462 seconds) while making a dictionary of indexes took 0.0041 seconds

Comment: @MonoShiro:  ok, but how does the overall time using this method compare to your method of deleting by index?

Comment: you should make m a set only once before the comprehension... and if this is faster will greatly depend on the size of m ... if there is only 2 or 3 elements in m this likely will provide little to no improvement

Comment: @Gerrat With that fixed the run time improved to 0.00399 :)

Comment: The only improvement I can think of is to generate items of the output list one at a time, using either a generator expression (`(i for i in ...)`) or as a generator function (`for i in l:  if ...:  yield i`).  That would allow any later uses of the output to "bail out" early if they discover they won't need all the data, although it wouldn't help in cases where the whole list is required.

Comment: @MonoShiro this is faster because set lookup is O(1)

Answer (score 1):

if you can store only the indices to be deleted in the list temp

```
temp = [0,2,...]
```

then this could work faster

```
np.delete(l,temp)
```

Comment: This is currently the fastest (0.00199 seconds). But it does require you to get the indexes first though...

Comment: If you're going to remove arbitrary items by index from a list, sort those indices in _reverse_ order.  That will minimize the useless "slide left" operations... although there will still be lots of them.